# Which one is the guy in yellow? Is he Pat or Mat?

Tags: character, pat-and-mat

The excellent stop-motion animated series *Pat & Mat* portrays two DIY-enthusiast friends usually wearing a yellow and a red coat.

Which one is the guy in yellow? Is he Pat or Mat?

Comment: The same wiki article features a picture of the duo with a description confirming that Pat wears a yellow shirt.

Comment: @AnneDauntedGoFundMonica Could you make that an answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy In the absence of response from Anne I did it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The yellow shirt is Pat. Their T-shirt colour was also the reason for there ban in the past. As per [writersblockmagazine](https://writersblockmagazine.com/2017/05/16/a-je-to-or-doing-and-subverting-communism-with-pat-and-mat/):

> It nearly didn’t. After airing the pilot in 1976, the creators had to explain why they had specifically chosen red and yellow as the shirt colours of Pat and Mat, as the government’s Office for Press and Information believed that the creators were trying to make fun of the tensions between the Soviet Union and China that were rising during that time. The creators’ explanations were deemed unsatisfactory and further production of Pat and Mat was banned. To get around the ban, the creators worked under the cover of a Slovak studio from Bratislava and changed Mat’s shirt to grey. After the fall of the communist regime in 1989, Mat’s shirt was changed back to red.

Also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_%26_Mat) refers to the yellow shirt as Pat as referred in [comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99823/pat-mat-which-one-is-the-guy-in-yellow#comment168632_99823).

Even in their official [Eshop](https://www.shop.patmat.cz/?ls_dir_id=12) portal, Yellow T-shirt Plush toy is called Pat and red one Mat.